# Selection works funny in macos?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I bought new macbook and it runs macOS 10.13.6

My text selection isn't working normally.
When I select some text and push the physical key named delete, it often only deletes one character from the end of selection or from the beginning of selection as opposed to removing all selected text (which is what I expect)

Also when I type, it some times write some letters before cursor, not after cursor.

And thirdly when I select text and it does delete the text when I press delete. The blue selection sometimes isn't gone, but the blue strip is over the text that's still left. But only with the length the selection was made.
So when I have an url `www.test.com` and I select `com` and press delete the result is `www.test.` and selection covers `st.`, even thou I expected that the selection is gone.

As a programmer, this is super annoying. I took this problem to maintenance but they were no help. I'm not sure under what conditions it happens, it seems to be quite random. Most often it happens in Chrome browser, and not only inside the pages but also in address bar.

How can I pinpoint what’s changing the key board interpretation?

Comment: If you just bought it and this is happening often, you should have Apple replace it.  Especially if you're a programmer and you need this to be correct.  If it was me, I wouldn't worry about how to fix it here, I'd just return and replace it.

Comment: I’m going to try and clear up some typos and add one intentionally (your OS version might be wrong). For the purpose of this question, would you edit in two specific details - what OS version are you running? What one text editor do you want to fix first? (Once the first is reliable - you could ask a follow on question if another app also needs help - what fixes one editor might not fix them all) I hate to see a needless return and if you can fix this with software or learn something - it will help lots of switchers.

Comment: It runs 10.13.6 that's correct.
Well I can't return it that easly. They don't have to take it back, and it's been months now. (I'll update the question too)

Comment: Maybe related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51491/multi-selection-of-text-in-text-areas-chrome-sparrow-will-switch-keyboard-to